# Typeahead - Load on Demand

Tags: angularjs, typehead

**How to make Typeahead load on demand?** Ex: I do a search and it brings me 6 results (limitTo = 6) and as I go down (Scroll) if I pass the 6 results it will go to the api and return another 6 and so on. Reason for this is not to overload my api by working Asynchronous and neither load all my list in $scope.

Comment: `$scope` makes me think this is an Angular 1 question. If so please replace the angular tag with `AngularJS`.  That aside, your question may not get the types of responses you wish because you don't show what you've tried to do for others to help you fix your code

Comment: @BeetleJuice thanks my friend!

Comment: (thumbs_up) no problem.